# Google Maps Geocoding API: How to get city/region names *consistently* in English or local language?

Tags: internationalization, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

When I make the following request (note the `language=en` part!) with latitude & longitude for Warsaw, Poland,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.23,21.01&language=en`

I get a result list which includes the following:

**Result 3 (neighborhood):**

```
    {
            "address_components" : [
               {
                  "long_name" : "Śródmieście Północne",
                  "short_name" : "Śródmieście Północne",
                  "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "Śródmieście",
                  "short_name" : "Śródmieście",
                  "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "Warszawa",   <-- city in Polish
                  "short_name" : "Warszawa",
                  "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "Warszawa",
                  "short_name" : "Warszawa",
                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "Warszawa",
                  "short_name" : "Warszawa",
                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "mazowieckie",  <-- region in Polish
                  "short_name" : "mazowieckie",
                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
               },
               {
                  "long_name" : "Poland",
                  "short_name" : "PL",
                  "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
               }
            ],
         [...]
         "place_id" : "ChIJjaxkh4rMHkcR1lza9qbbnrU",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
    }
```

**Result 4 (sublocality_level_1):**

```
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Śródmieście",
               "short_name" : "Śródmieście",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Warsaw",   <-- city in English
               "short_name" : "Warsaw",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Warszawa",
               "short_name" : "Warszawa",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Warszawa",
               "short_name" : "Warszawa",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Masovian Voivodeship",  <-- region in English
               "short_name" : "Masovian Voivodeship",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Poland",
               "short_name" : "PL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         [...]
         "place_id" : "ChIJ8e41PvbMHkcRit4n8qe36Ns",
         "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
```

The main problem with this is the inconsistency for the same address components (locality, administrative_area_level_1) - sometimes English (as requested), sometimes the local language. Without some other ID to know that these refer to the same administrative reality, I can't be sure of that, unless I used another source of English & local geo names and did some pattern matching.

Is there a way to get around this problem? Or could someone suggest a reverse geocoding service not having such issues?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I wrote an `if/else` group to grab location data in order of preference.

```
foreach ($data->results[0]->address_components as $stuff) {
    // city
    if ($stuff->types[0] == 'locality') {
        $zip->locality_short = $stuff->short_name;
        $zip->locality_long = $stuff->long_name;
    } elseif ($stuff->types[0] == 'sublocality_level_1') {
        $zip->locality_short = $stuff->short_name;
        $zip->locality_long = $stuff->long_name;
    } elseif ($stuff->types[0] == 'neighborhood') {
        $zip->locality_short = $stuff->short_name;
        $zip->locality_long = $stuff->long_name;
    }
    // state
    if ($stuff->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
        $zip->location_short = $stuff->short_name;
        $zip->location_long = $stuff->long_name;
    }
    // country
    if ($stuff->types[0] == 'country') {
        $zip->country_short = $stuff->short_name;
        $zip->country_long = $stuff->long_name;
    }
}
```